# calling a function during a scroll game

Tags: python

I am making a scroll game for my final project in my computer science class, which is when the background just keeps going on and on (horizontally in my case). I have functions for obstacles and my problem is that I want the function to be called again when the background moves on from the initial 1200x650 screen. Here is an example of the code I used for one of my obstacles. I don't know how to keep calling the function after the background moves on. Thank you!

```
ox = 1150  
oy = randint(100,500)
obstaclecount = 0

def obstacles():
    global ox,oy

laserobstacles = screen.blit(obstaclez,(ox,oy))

ox -= 10  #moving from right to left on screen
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: For starters, calling the function repeatedly will likely use some sort of loop.  Just what depends very much on your program architecture, especially the way you've implemented movement in this world.

Comment: The position of the obstacles would be a function of the "state" of the world, i.e. how has the screen changed since the last call (which i assume is a movement in either direction). Tracking the scrolling would probably happen in a loop where you would make this function call. We need to know a lot more about your architecture to provide a better answer.